# How to clear an autocomplete material ui field based on another autocomplete field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

**Summary of the issue**

I have two Autocomplete fields from Material UI. The first one (A) takes in a list of districts in a city, and the second one (B), a list of neighbourhoods, which varies depending on the district selected in A. B is disabled if there is no value selected in A. Everything is working as intended, except for two minor details.

1. When you select values both on A and B, and then clear the value from A, the value from B isn't cleared.
2. When you select values both on A and B and then change the value on A, in B you still have a neighbourhood which doesn't belong to the new district. I would like to prevent this from happening.

I have tried setting the neighbourhood to `null` whenever there is a change on A, but that doesn't change the value displayed on B.

**Information and code to reproduce**

I have created a custom autocomplete component based on the Autocomplete field from Material UI:

```
const Autosuggest = props => (
  <Autocomplete
    options={props.options}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.title || option}
    value={props.value}
    style={props.style}
    onChange={props.onChange}
    disabled={props.disabled}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label={props.label}
        type={props.type}
        variant={props.variant}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

I included two instances of it in another Wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper = props  => {
  // Some variables
  const {selectedDistrict} = props
  let district = selectedDistrict ? selectedDistrict.title : "";
  let neighbourhoods = selectedDistrict ? selectedDistrict.neighbourhoods : [];
  return (
    <Div>
    <Autosuggest
       options={props.autosuggestData}
       value={district}
       onChange={props.setDistrict}
       variant="outlined"
       label="Distrito"
       style={AutosuggestStyle}
     />
      <Autosuggest
       key={props.selectedNeighbourhood}
       options={neighbourhoods}
       value={props.selectedNeighbourhood}
       disabled={district ? false : true}
       onChange={props.setNeighbourhood}
       variant="outlined"
       label="Barrio"
       style={AutosuggestStyle}
     />
 </Div>
  );
};
```

Then I use the wrapper in the main App component:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      district: "",
      neighbourhood: ""
    }

    this.setDistrict = this.setDistrict.bind(this);
    this.setNeighbourhood = this.setNeighbourhood.bind(this);
  }

  // Methods

  setDistrict = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({
      district: value,
      neighbourhood: null
    }, () => console.log("New district set: ", this.state.district))
  }

  setNeighbourhood = (event, value) => {
    let hood = value ? value : null;

    this.setState({
      neighbourhood: hood
    }, () => console.log("New neighbourhood set: ", this.state.neighbourhood))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper 
        autosuggestData={districts}
        setDistrict={this.setDistrict}
        setNeighbourhood={this.setNeighbourhood}
        selectedDistrict={this.state.district}
        selectedNeighbourhood={this.selectedNeighbourhood}
      />
    
    )
  }
}
```

This is a sample of the districts and neighbourhoods I'm using:

```
let districts = [
  {
    title: "Ciutat Vella",
    neighbourhoods : [
      {title : "La Barceloneta"},
      {title : "El Gòtic"},
      {title : "El Raval"},
      {title : "Sant Pere"},
      {title : "Santa Caterina i la Ribera"}
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Eixample",
    neighbourhoods : [
      {title : "L'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample"},
      {title : "La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample"},
      {title : "Dreta de l'Eixample"},
      {title : "Fort Pienc"},
      {title : "Sagrada Família"},
      {title : "Sant Antoni"},
    ] 
  }
]
```